# SQLite with Javascript windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, mobile, windows-8

i am in between some where while working with windows 8 app with database sqlite. Not finding any proper help.
i got one article http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx
but sory to say i m not geting how and where to use this code

```
1: var dbPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path + '\\db.sqlite';
   2: SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath)
   3:   .then(function (db) {
   4:     return db.runAsync('CREATE TABLE Item (name TEXT, price REAL, id INT PRIMARY KEY)');
   5:   })
   6:   .then(function (db) {
   7:     return db.runAsync('INSERT INTO Item (name, price, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', ['Mango', 4.6, 123]);
   8:   })
   9:   .then(function (db) {
  10:     return db.eachAsync('SELECT * FROM Item', function (row) {
  11:       console.log('Get a ' + row.name + ' for $' + row.price);
  12:     });
  13:   })
  14:   .then(function (db) {
  15:     db.close();
  16:   });
```

the problem is that i am not getting how to use,

i have few TextBox value wanted to save in SQLite Database, but i m not figuring out. to let you know again. i am using Windows Store app using JavaScript (Windows)

Please, let me know how to do this and how can i get out from this loop

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is just some sample code which creates an 'item' table and inserts and selects some records as an example on how to use the API.
After calling SQLite3JS.openAsync, you should probably keep the database connection object (until suspend of the app) and use it for subsequent calls to either runAsync, allAsync, oneAsync. The first one just executes a single statement, the second returns all rows from a select statement and oneAsync will just return the first row from a select statement as an Object.

However, depending on what you want to do, [ApplicationData.localSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) or [ApplicationData.roamingSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx) might be more suited to your needs, especially if you don't have experience with RDBMS/SQLite.

Comment: now suppose i wanted to save data in SQLite from input type text by pressing input button, how can i ?